# macOS 10.14.3 runs incredibly slow on my iMac

Tags: macos, imac

I updated to macOS Mojave 10.14.3 on a 27" iMac with 16 GB memory, and it is running super slow. It can take upto a minute to see the login screen, Preview is super slow. New folders are slow. Any help?

macOS Mojave 10.14.2 ran fine on the same machine. How do I resolve?

Comment: Can you upgrade it to macOS Mojave 10.14.4 and check if that brings thing back to normal?

Comment: WAY better! Thank you. Some things are still unreasonably slow, but the major problems are fixed. And, finally, Preview now opens live PDF forms.

Answer (score 2):

As on now, macOS Mojave 10.14.4 is the latest stable release. Consider updating your iMac and see if that fixes the performance issues.

What you are observing may be due to performance optimization related issues.